# How to rorate an image on infopath form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, infopath

I am using SharePoint 2013, in this I am using InfoPath version 2013 . I want to rotate an image which is included on the form. How I can do this. Is there any idea.

Answer (score 1):

Per my test, we cannot rotate an image in the InfoPath form.

You need to rotate the image using Windows tools, such as Windows Photo Viewer or Paint firstly. Then, insert it into the form.